# How to add cell to dynamic collection view using swift

Tags: ios, insert, swift2, uicollectionview, cell

[image]

In top of that image you can see some images and plus button I want to do like this in my app so i used collection view to get this view and everything works fine but i cant add cell to my dynamic collection view can some one help me to do this process

code in my view controller:

```
 import UIKit
import Alamofire
import SwiftyJSON
import SDWebImage
import SwiftElegantDropdownMenu
class EditPendingViewController: UIViewController,UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource,UITextViewDelegate,UICollectionViewDelegate,UICollectionViewDataSource,UIImagePickerControllerDelegate,UINavigationControllerDelegate{



var pendingImageString:[String]!

 @IBOutlet var editPendingCollectionvIEW: UICollectionView!
 override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

 }

 func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        return pendingImageString.count
    }
    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("editPendingCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as!MypendindeditCollectionViewCell
        let img:NSString = pendingImageString[indexPath.item]
        cell.editImage.sd_setImageWithURL(NSURL(string: imageApikey + (img as String)))
        cell.contentView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor().CGColor
        cell.contentView.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
        return cell
    }

}
```

I have not done any process for adding cell to my collection view i just loaded the data from the server.now help to add the cell

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return pendingImageString.count + 1 // + 1 for last cell
}

override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell : CollectionViewCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(reuseIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell
     cell.btn.tag = indexPath.row

     if indexPath.item = pendingImageString.count {
       cell.imageview = //your static image that is shown in last cell
       cell.cancelButton.isHidden = true
     }
     else{
         let img:NSString = pendingImageString[indexPath.item]
         cell.editImage.sd_setImageWithURL(NSURL(string: imageApikey + (img as String)))
         cell.cancelButton.isHidden = false
     }

}

override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
     if indexPath.item = pendingImageString.count{
       // update your array with new image file
     }
}

// cancel button action
func buttonClicked(sender: UIButton?) {
    let tag = sender.tag
        // remove object from array and reload collectionview        
}
```

Comment: My code is available in obj-c make sure you have done in swift

Comment: i need to add additional cell to my collection view from that cell i want to perform action.understood??

Comment: wait let me change my code work for simple things in swift

Comment: Action target is your cancel button action, if you done this from storyboard then don't write. check updated answer.

Comment: in that image you can see five images after that there is cell which having the plus image that is additional inserted cell from that cell i should perform action

Comment: Iam just loading data from the server to collection view now additionally i want to add cell to that collection view thats it.how to do that one

Comment: Check now. Add + 1 cell for last cell and put condition for every where for that cell

Comment: it says error as fatal error index out of range at the line: let img:NSString = pendingImageString[indexPath.item]

Comment: Bro you need to set condition for this thats what I already mention. Check updated answer in `cellForItem` thats how you have to put condition for last cell.

Comment: but i also want to display those images from the server so i want to this line know let img:NSString = pendingImageString[indexPath.item

Comment: Yeah this condition will do same. It sets all the images that are coming from server. when your array(pendingImageString) get finished then add static ADD image in your imageview which is in collectionview and hides its cancel button . thats it.

Answer (score 1):

On click of last cell of the collection view add logic to enter your product in the database then just reload the collection view

```
   func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if indexPath.row == pendingImageString.count - 1
        {
            //TODO - add item to database and reload collectionview
        }
    }
```

Comment: am asking how to insert the additional cell to dynamic collection view from that cell i want to perform action please understand my question

Comment: thats what i am telling on tap of add button you will add logic where your items gets add to database and since you are loading the object from database after reload collection view will be populated with the new cell

Comment: there is no button in my view controller every process should done by collection view only.am just loading data from the server to collection view now additionally i want to add cell to that collection view thats it.how to do that one

Comment: show all the data in collection view like you have shown in the image and have a extra cell in the collection view which i am referring as add button on click of this extra cell you can add items to database and reload the collection view